# Most efficient way of importing files from children folders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent directory that contains children directories, where each contains an SVG component and I only need to import some of them. I'm currently importing all the components I need by doing this:

```
import FacebookIcon from 'project/icons/Facebook';
import TwitterIcon from 'project/icons/Twitter';
import DiscordIcon from 'project/icons/Discord';
import MediumIcon from 'project/icons/Medium';
import YoutubeIcon from 'project/icons/Youtube';
```

However this seems very verbose. Is there a less verbose way of doing this?

I thought about destructuring, but I wasn't sure how to do this since each file is in a different folder.

Comment: *this seems very verbose* ... no. it's ok

Comment: Unless you have to repeat those imports in many places. In that case I'd add an `index.js` file in `project/icons` to export them all and then when importing you'll need just `import Icons from "project/icons` and you'll use them with `Icons.Facebook` (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you want to import similar components from a single source (you will get auto-complete too):

```
import {
  FacebookIcon,
  TwitterIcon,
  DiscordIcon,
  DiscordIcon,
  MediumIcon,
  YoutubeIcon,
} from "project/icons";

// Usage
<FacebookIcon/>

// Same
import Icons from './project/icons';

// Usage
const Icon = Icons.FacebookIcon;
<Icon/>
```

To achieve this, create `index.js` file in `project/icons` and make **named export** for each of the components.

```
export { default as FacebookIcon } from "./FacebookIcon";
...
```

---